# Docker on Windows Server 2016: The process cannot access the file

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I installed Docker 18.09.1 on multiple Windows Server 2016 (1607) and they all fail to pull images.

The error is always **"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."**

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker pull microsoft/nanoserver
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/nanoserver
bce2fbc256ea: Extracting [==================================================>]  252.7MB/252.7MB
6f2071dcd729: Download complete
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\0fe9c9d35018da5b4c48cfcb389629f3071d040c737c46fa7cc07855fc97cc3e\UtilityVM: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

What I have tried so far:

- Uninstalled anti virus -> no change
- Checked with Process Monitor if some other process blocks the file -> Only dockerd.exe ever uses the folder.
- Disabled almost all running services and killed all running processes that I thought could interfere and are not needed to run Windows -> no change
- Reinstalled Docker -> no change

I am lost and have no idea what to try next. Searching for this error almost always leads to users having problems with security software, but I already uninstalled my anti virus. Also Process Monitor somehow seems to indicate that it is Docker blocking its own files.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you really completely uninstalled Antivir/endpoint protection etc.? not only deactivating.... which product btw?

Comment: Yes, I completely removed all Sophos components. In the meantime I was able to get it running on a newly installed 2016 server including Sophos. But reinstalling all those servers is not really something I want to do at the moment.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this yet?  I've tried exactly the same steps that Mirantis recommends which is exactly what you did.  

I have 3 servers and 1 out of the 3 can extract correctly and run.  Same Server OS version, Same Docker EE Client and Server version.  1 of the 2 that isn't working has Cylance completely uninstalled and Windows Defender off.